# Что такое сайт-транзитка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Прислали мне такое задание, нужно сделать

1. сделать лендинг с нуля
2. сделать транзитку  нуля

С первым понятно, а вот сайт транзитка?
Впервые слышу, что это за зверь такой?

Comment: и это всё ТЗ? только эти два пункта? ни названия, ни кол-во блоков, тематики, ожидаемых текстов, предпочтений и т.д.?

Comment: Это даже не терминология, а жаргонизм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Транзитная страница ("прелендинг"), в основном нужна для «разогрева» потенциальных клиентов для повышения конверсии на сайте оффера. В связи с этими задачами прелендинг, может выглядеть как тематический сайт, блог известного человека или форум и на нем впрямую ничего не должно продаваться, а в текст ненавязчиво вставлены Ваши партнерские ссылки. Такая прокладка должна мотивировать трафик на целевое действие на основной посадочной странице.

Answer (score 1):

**Транзитка (прокладка, прокла, прелендинг)** – страница, предшествующая переходу на лендинг. Она создает эмоциональный фон, содержит в себе тонну полезной информации о товаре, повышает уровень доверия и всячески подогревает потенциального клиента к совершению покупки.